# How to use PHP7 with Mysql?

Tags: mysql, php-7

As we all know PHP 7 removed the Mysql and kept only mysqli and PDO.

But I have some condition on my project to use the PHP7 with Mysql, how can i handle that, without changing too much of code or existing extensions?

Comment: you can't use php7 with mysql_functions - they're removed - just update code :)

Comment: Well if you have the bandwidth, you can use now as an excuse to completely refactor away any dependence on **mysql**, since it has known security holes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define almost all `mysql_*` functions using MySQLi or PDO in separated file, which you can include on top of your project. This is my solution: https://github.com/sunhater/php7-mysql